# What's the most efficient way of loading and later referencing texture tiles in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, object, pixi.js

Recently I began working on a simple platformer game as a way of learning pixi.js and object orientation in javascript. Currently, I'm saving levels in a textfile like so:

```
11111111111
10001200001
10601201001
10104001551
13331111111
```

Where each number corresponds to a different tile, ex. 1 = solid, 3 = spikes, 5 = switch, etc.

With each tile having their own, often unique properties, how can I structure my code so that creating and referencing tiles is as simple and easy as possible? Should each tile have its own constructor, or should I create just one that takes in lots of parameters? Should each rendered block be its own object, or is there any simpler way of referencing to each tile?

If I need to provide more information, make sure to tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

btw use ascii characters for your level, it's easier to read.

Personally, I use a class for every tile that's pretty different from every other, but if you create a tile that **SUPER** similar to another, just create a class that is similar to both, and those similar tiles can be class extensions. For example, I have an `Enemy` class that has MANY sub-classes: the enemy types. I have a sub-class of `Enemy` called `Basic` which a basic enemy, but I have also have a sub-class called `Machine_Gun` which shoots faster.

To read the level data, just use a switch case:

```
for(var y = 0; y < levels[level_number]; y++) {

    for(var x = 0; x < levels[level_number][y]; x++) {

        switch(levels[level_number][y][x]) {

            case "#": floor.push(new Floor(x * 20, y * 20)); break;

            case "O": coins.push(new Coin(x * 20, y * 20)); break;

            case "@": player.y = (x * 20) - 1; player.x = (y * 20) - 1; break;

            case "&": monsters.push(new Basic(x * 20, y * 20)); break;

            case "%": monsters.push(new Machine_Gun(x * 20, y * 20)); break;

            default: break; // something else like air.

        }

    }

}
```

Then, my levels can be like this:

```
levels = [

    [

        "##########", // MUCH easier to understand (for me at least)
        "#OO     %#",
        "###     ##",
        "# @     &#",
        "##########"

    ], [

        "###############",
        "#           & #",
        "#          ####",
        "#             #",
        "#     ###     #",
        "#           O #",
        "# @        ####",
        "####          #",
        "#O     %   %  #",
        "###############"

    ]

];
```

Just like that, you can easily create levels.